# Microsoft Flow mail body multipart syntax

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to get the HTML part of an e-mails multipart body. 
There is a function named 'multipartBody' that I'm trying to use, but I can't get the syntax right.

This is not accepted by Flow. How would I have to write it?

> multipartBody(@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Body']},1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `multipartBody()` expects first parameter to be an action name like `Send an instant message` or `When a new email arrives` etc. The supported multipart content type is `multipart/*`.

So the correct usage of this function basing on above example is `multipartBody('Apply_to_each', 1)`.

BTW; I am afraid is not the function you are looking for.